Multiple Borrows Error For simple application
I have been trying to learn Rust by developing small programs, however the learning curve is more steep than I thought.
I have been playing with the following code snippet which does not work because of a borrowing compiler error.
It's a simple program, in which you have a dictionary of custom objects. Based on some conditions, some values will be mutated, whilst others will be deleted from the dictionary.
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Define the Custom struct
pub struct Custom {
    x: u8,
}

fn main() {
    // Create a HashMap with string keys and Custom objects as values
    let mut custom_map: HashMap<String, Custom> = HashMap::new();

    // Insert some sample data into the map
    custom_map.insert("apple".to_string(), Custom { x: 10 });
    custom_map.insert("banana".to_string(), Custom { x: 20 });
    custom_map.insert("grape".to_string(), Custom { x: 30 });
    custom_map.insert("quince".to_string(), Custom { x: 40 }); // Example entry with 'q'

    let mut elements_to_be_deleted: Vec<&String> = Vec::new();

    // Iterate over the keys and values in the map
    for (key, custom) in &mut custom_map {
        if key.contains('a') {
            // Increment the x property for keys containing 'a'
            custom.x += 1;
        }

        if key.contains('q') {
            // Remove entries with 'q' from the map
            elements_to_be_deleted.push(key);
        }
    }

    // iterate over the keys that need to be deleted
    for key in &elements_to_be_deleted {
        custom_map.remove(*key);
    }

    // Print the updated values
    for (key, custom) in &custom_map {
        println!("Key: {}, x: {}", key, custom.x);
    }
}

The compiler error is the following:
   |
21 |     for (key, custom) in &mut custom_map {
   |                          --------------- first mutable borrow occurs here

34 |     for key in &elements_to_be_deleted {
   |                ----------------------- first borrow later used here
35 |         custom_map.remove(*key);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

Ok, I understand, I cannot have both the mutable variable itself and a mutable reference to it in the same lifecycle.
I changed the above code and offloaded the mutation operations in separate functions
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Define the Custom struct
pub struct Custom {
    x: u8,
}

fn main() {
    // Create a HashMap with string keys and Custom objects as values
    let mut custom_map: HashMap<String, Custom> = HashMap::new();

    // Insert some sample data into the map
    custom_map.insert("apple".to_string(), Custom { x: 10 });
    custom_map.insert("banana".to_string(), Custom { x: 20 });
    custom_map.insert("grape".to_string(), Custom { x: 30 });
    custom_map.insert("quince".to_string(), Custom { x: 40 }); // Example entry with 'q'

    let mut elements_to_be_deleted: Vec<&String> = Vec::new();

    // Iterate over the keys and values in the map
    for (key, custom) in &custom_map {
        if key.contains('q') {
            // Remove entries with 'q' from the map
            elements_to_be_deleted.push(&key);
        }
    }

    // modify map elements
    modifyMapElements(&mut custom_map);

    //delete map elements
    deleteElementsFromMap(&mut custom_map, elements_to_be_deleted);

    // Print the updated values
    for (key, custom) in &custom_map {
        println!("Key: {}, x: {}", key, custom.x);
    }
}

fn deleteElementsFromMap(map: &mut HashMap<String, Custom>, els_to_delete: Vec<&String>) {
    for key in elements_to_be_deleted {
        map.remove(&key);
    }
}

fn modifyMapElements(map: &mut HashMap<String, Custom>) {
    for (key, custom) in map {
        if key.contains('a') {
            // Increment the x property for keys containing 'a'
            custom.x += 1;
        }
    }
}

The compiler error for this snippet is this:
   for (key, custom) in &custom_map {
   |                          ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
32 |     deleteElementsFromMap(&mut custom_map, elements_to_be_deleted);
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ---------------------- immutable borrow later used here
   |                           |
   |                           mutable borrow occurs here

I have tried enclosing the for loop which iterates immutably over the map in  a separate block, but it solves nothing
    {
        // Iterate over the keys and values in the map
        for (key, custom) in &custom_map {
            if key.contains('q') {
                // Remove entries with 'q' from the map
                elements_to_be_deleted.push(&key);
            }
        }
    }

I get it, you cannot have mutable and immutable references for a variable on the same scopes.
My question is, how to design the code above to use the Rust reference system to my advantage ?
I am more interested in learning how to think and design this piece of  code as a Rust developer, so I wouldn't be particularily interested in workarounds.

You can use HashMap::retain to iterate & remove in the same loop.
use std::collections::HashMap;

// Define the Custom struct
pub struct Custom {
    x: u8,
}

fn main() {
    // Create a HashMap with string keys and Custom objects as values
    let mut custom_map: HashMap<String, Custom> = HashMap::new();

    // Insert some sample data into the map
    custom_map.insert("apple".to_string(), Custom { x: 10 });
    custom_map.insert("banana".to_string(), Custom { x: 20 });
    custom_map.insert("grape".to_string(), Custom { x: 30 });
    custom_map.insert("quince".to_string(), Custom { x: 40 }); // Example entry with 'q'

    // Iterate over the keys and values in the map
    custom_map.retain(|key, custom| {
        if key.contains('a') {
            // Increment the x property for keys containing 'a'
            custom.x += 1;
        }

        // Only retain entries with no 'q'
        !key.contains('q')
    });

    // Print the updated values
    for (key, custom) in &custom_map {
        println!("Key: {}, x: {}", key, custom.x);
    }
}

